# google sheets array formula for counting the number of times a value appears in comparison to another value

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, syntax

I am trying to get the count for how often a value appears in comparison to another.
Here is the Array.
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A2:A)=2,"Manual Type",IF(B2:B="","",COUNTIF('2021ContractsData'!L:L,"Where L='Manual (M)'",B2:B))))

B already has the populated listings to compare to.
2021ContractsData'!L:L is column with only 2 options in its drop down.
First drop down option is Manual (M).
I am needing a count of how many times the value in L column appears in comparison to B.
My error is an arguement error. CountIF is looking for 2 and sees 3.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Player0, showed me a differnet method.
Ive used this and get zero's
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Manual Type";COUNTIF('2021ContractsData'!L3:L="Manual (M)",UNIQUE(B3:B))})

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Manual Type"; 
 COUNTIF(2021ContractsData!B3:B, 2021ContractsData!L3:L="Manual (M)")})
```

Comment: No Good, gave me all zero's, we would need to add the unique command as well.

Comment: IF I use this I get 0 on each but with the correct count of B(Unique)

=ARRAYFORMULA({"Manual Type";COUNTIF('2021ContractsData'!L3:L="Manual (M)",UNIQUE(B3:B))})

Comment: @geneavone can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with the following.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A2:A)=2,"Manual Type",IF(B2:B="","",COUNTIFS('2021ContractsData'!L2:L,"Manual(M)",'2021ContractsData'!H2:H,B2:B))))